# Gnome Titlebar height

Tags: gnome, gtk, gtk3, titlebar, window-buttons

I have Gnome 3.36 and I wondered if it's possible to change the titlebar height.
For example in Chrome I have a big title bar but in my Chrome PWA I have a smaller titlebar (screenshot).
Is it similar to make the PWA title bar as high as the normal Chrome titlebar?

I'm not only having this in chrome apps. Many different apps have different titlebar height.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Please provide OS/release details

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [link](https://larryreznick.com/2019/05/17/shrinking-the-bar/). However it works only for some applications like the terminal and vscode. I dont think so it will work for chrome. However its still a good option.

[Terminal titlebar after applying the changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d5Xe.png)

PS: if you are looking for a clean browser, I suggest to use Firefox and in Customize section you can reduce the bars width and even remove some of them. Gives a nice clean look.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that without functioning web links it would be useless (and web links can break time to time). That's why it would be better to include or at least summarize in your answer the information that those linked pages present.

Comment: Oops! That page can’t be found.